# How to get the related date if the company name is duplicated in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the date corresponding to the company name if the company name is duplicated.

[Public google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit?usp=sharing)

| Company date | date | duplicated company date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | jan1 |  |
| two | jan1 |  |
| one | feb1 | jan1 (find this using some formula) |
| two | feb4 | jan1 |
| two | mar3 | feb4 (if repeated take the previous date) |
| three | apr1 |  |
| four | apr5 |  |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to do this. Especially if we don't know why we are doing this in the first place.

[image]

The closest I could get is using `FILTER`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($B$2:$B2;$A$2:$A2=$A3);COUNTA(FILTER($B$2:$B2;$A$2:$A2=$A3)));"")
```

Place this in the second row of your data (the 3rd row of your table if you have headers), because it will not work for the first row. Then, you drag this formula down for all your rows.

**Note:**

- A2 is where I had the first company, like "Apple"
- B2 is where I had the first date, like "Jan 1"

You can place this formula in C3, and drag-copy to all rows beneath it using the colored square in the bottom-right corner of the cell you have highlighted.

[image]

*(In case you didn't know)*

Have fun! ^_^

Comment: I have added this to the [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit#gid=837079760) :)

Comment: Yeah, fixed some formatting stuff. But it is working like they wanted. (As far as I am aware)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, and quite ugly :D Maybe if we knew what they needed this data for, I could've solved it some other way. Oh well...

Comment: They weren't replying to comments or messages on the Google Sheet   ╯ᆺ╰

Comment: @Chrimle Apologies for late reply, The code works for the dummy data, but for the original data it gives me numbers unlike the Date, Please have a look at updated google sheets.

Comment: Oh, that's because dates in Excel/Google Sheets are just numbers. You need to tell it that those are not regular numbers, but dates. So you select the cells you want to be dates, and go to "Formatting/Formats" at the top, go to "Numbers" and there you can find all sorts of formats for dates. If you want the "12-feb" format, go to the bottom of that drop down list and find something like "Custom date and time formats". Clicking there, you will get a bunch of different options, the "12-feb" one can be found there :)